# Active Record Association Error - Undefined Method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I have the following line of code which seems to work okay.

```
<% current_user.blockedshows.map(&:tvshows).each_with_index do |blocked, index| %>
```

However, when I call it on `blocked.title` and `image_tag(blocked.image)`, (full code below) I am getting the following error:  `undefined method title for <ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy_Tvshow:0x007fd4e24b9448>`

View

```
<%= blocked.title %>
<%= image_tag(blocked.image) %> </br>

 Tweets containing the following keywords will be removed from your timeline: </br>

    <%@keywords = blocked.phrases.map(&:text) %>
    <%=@keywords %> </br>
```

Blockedshow Model

```
class Blockedshow < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tvshows
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Tvshow Model

```
class Tvshow < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :phrases
    belongs_to :blockedshow
end
```

Tvshow Table

```
class CreateTvShows < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :tvshows do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.string :image 

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `tvshows` itself is an ActiveRecord association object.
You need to loop over it also:

```
current_user.blockedshows.map(&:tvshows).each_with_index do |blocked, index|
  blocked.each do |b|
    <%= b.title %>
  end 
end
```

Comment: Thanks! Now i am getting the error `SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: tvshows.blockedshow_id: SELECT "tvshows".* FROM "tvshows"  WHERE "tvshows"."blockedshow_id" = ?`